Proof of $\text{Cor} \circ \text{Res}=[n]$ for group cohomology
Let $G$ be an abelian group and $M$ a $G$-module. The basic definitions:
Let $H < G$ be a subgroup of finite index $n$. We have a map $tr: H^0(H, M) \rightarrow H^0(G, M)$ on group cohomology defined by $m \mapsto \sum_{g \in G/H} gm$. This can be extended to a map $H^*(H, M) \rightarrow H^*(G, M)$ of cohomological functors.
It is explicitly written down as following and called $$\text{Cor} : H^1(H,M)\to H^1(G,M)$$.
Let $f$ be a cocyle for $H$. Take a set of representatives $X$ of $G/H$ in $G$. Then $\operatorname{Cor}(f)(g) = \sum_{x \in X} y\cdot f(y^{-1}gx)$ where $y\in X$ is the unique representative such that $gxH=yH$. Then $\operatorname{Cor}(f)$ is a cocycle whose class is the well-defined corestriction of the class of $f$. Let $\text{Res} : H^1(G,M)\to H^1(H,M)$.
I want to prove that $\text{cor}\circ \text{Res}=[n]$ where $[n]$ is multiplication by n.
But the expression $(\operatorname{Cor}\circ \text{Res})(f)(g) = \sum_{x \in X} y\cdot (\text{res}f)(y^{-1}gx)$・・・① seems very far from multiplication by $n$.
How can I prove ① is multiplication by $n$?

First, an annoying meta-remark, this isn't really the right way to prove this, you should instead use a dévissage style argument and reduce the proof to $H^0$ (where it's trivial, since each $g$ is acting trivially on the $m$ in your sum when $m \in M^G$).
Second, if you really want to prove it this way, it will work. Since you are looking at the restriction of $f$, in the symbols of the form $f(y^{-1}gx)$, you can expand according to the cocycle relation, and cancel coboundaries.
